# How can I send an invoice to a participant, manually, without double sending

Tags: civievent, invoice, payment, participants, paylater

workflow:
I would like to use event registration with option "pay later". After a check I would like to change the participant status and send an invoice. I dont' find a way to do this automatically, but it is also ok do to this manually. The participant registration and also the invoices should be happen over a year, so I need to know if the participants have already received an invoice, to prevent someone getting the invoice twice.

question:

1. is there a way to send an invoice after changing the participant status?
2. how to filter out participants which have already received an invoice?

thanks for your help David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

daveawe12323, welcome to stack exchange civicrm.

There are two ways of sending notification to user

1. Send Event receipt.

When you edit the participant using backend participant form, you should see 'Send confirmation' option. When checked the participant will receive receipt about the event having details of event and payment. But no activity will recorded in the system when a receipt is send.

[image]

2. Send Tax invoice

If you have ['Tax and invoicing'](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/invoicing/) enabled, than you can create a invoice on the payment. You can download the invoice and send via email or you can email the invoice from CiviCRM. Both the option will create activity in Civi to track when the invoice was downloaded or emailed.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I din't find the button, because it's only called confirmation.